# The hadoop task didn't proceed in a psuedo-distributed mode

Tags: hadoop

I tried to use Hadoop, then installed and could use as a stand-alone mode.
But when I use as a psuedo-distributed mode, below message was occurred and didn't proceed the process.

```
17/10/24 02:04:15 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032

17/10/24 02:04:16 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 10

17/10/24 02:04:16 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:10

17/10/24 02:04:17 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1508778206216_0001

17/10/24 02:04:17 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1508778206216_0001

17/10/24 02:04:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://MacBook.local:8088/proxy/application_1508778206216_0001/

17/10/24 02:04:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1508778206216_0001
```

I checked localhost:50070 and there are a working Datanode.
I show my setup procedure.

①Install Hadoop

```
brew install hadoop
```

②hadoop configurations
○libexec/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

○libexec/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

○libexec/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
</property>
```

---

○libexec/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:54311</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

③start hadoop

```
sbin/start-all.sh
```

with jps

- ResourceManager
- NodeManager
- SecondaryNameNode
- NameNode
- DataNode

worked.

④Run of Hadoop

```
hadoop jar libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.8.1.jar pi 10 100000
```

then

```
Number of Maps  = 10
Samples per Map = 100000
17/10/24 02:04:12 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Wrote input for Map #2
Wrote input for Map #3
Wrote input for Map #4
Wrote input for Map #5
Wrote input for Map #6
Wrote input for Map #7
Wrote input for Map #8
Wrote input for Map #9
Starting Job
17/10/24 02:04:15 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
17/10/24 02:04:16 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 10
17/10/24 02:04:16 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:10
17/10/24 02:04:17 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1508778206216_0001
17/10/24 02:04:17 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1508778206216_0001
17/10/24 02:04:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://MacBook.local:8088/proxy/application_1508778206216_0001/
17/10/24 02:04:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1508778206216_0001
```

The process never proceeded.
Please tell me the reason why it doesn't work. And I accessed "http://macbook.local:8088/proxy/application_1508759907777_0001/" to check Jobtracker, but an error code "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" was returned.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that Hadoop 2.x uses the YARN Resource Managers and Node Managers *in place of* Job Trackers and Task Trackers.

Instead, you can try adding the following property to `yarn-site.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
</property>
```

I'm not sure what is supposed to happen to `jobtracker` properties in Hadoop 2.x, but perhaps it is interfering. Dropping it and explicitly setting the `resourcemanager.hostname` may resolve.

You can test if it's available by opening `localhost:8032` in a browser. More information on setting up a pseudo-distributed cluster is available in the [Apache Hadoop docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#YARN_on_a_Single_Node).

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I added that property, and job proceeded. But the meaasage "INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1508759907777_0001" was occurred and stop proceeding:(

Comment: I couldn't access localhost:8032. This page shows "It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. This is not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon."
Don't I have to access by web browser?

Comment: That "Hadoop IPC port" message means the Resource Manager is up and running on that port, so that's good. What happened after you saw the "Running job" message? Did it emit another error? Did it just hang forever? If so, how long did you wait to kill?

Comment: I'm not sure how long the pi example job takes to run ... maybe try a smaller 2nd arg than 100,000?

Comment: Also, I had to replace `macbook.local` with `localhost` in the url it spits out.

Comment: I was waiting for at least 3 hours, but the process didn't end. And I changed 2nd arg 100,000 to 1,000, the result was same.
I accessed "http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1508778206216_0002/" but there are no responses.

Comment: I tried to same things on centos 7 server, then I could use as psuedo-distributed mode. thanks.
But, another error has occurred so I'll make another question.